# What is the difference between SureFire JUnitCore and JUnit4 Runners

Tags: maven, junit, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin, junit-runner

Maven surefire has

- JUnit4 Runner
  http://maven.apache.org/surefire/surefire-providers/surefire-junit4/index.html
- JUnitCore Runner 
  http://maven.apache.org/surefire/surefire-providers/surefire-junit47/index.html

What is the difference between them?

I notice, that property excludedGroups work in surefire-junit47, but doesn't work in surefire-junit4
Why?

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
               <excludedGroups>my.com.IntegrationDB</excludedGroups>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i wouldn't defined the surefire-junitXXX manually. Better let surefire do it's job. Furthermore an excerpt from the docs:

> (TestNG/JUnit47 provider with JUnit4.8+ only) Excluded groups. Any
>   methods/classes/etc with one of the groups specified in this list will
>   specifically not be run. For JUnit, this parameter forces the use of
>   the 4.7 provider This parameter is ignored if the suiteXmlFiles
>   parameter is specified.

See also for groups:

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#Using_JUnit_Categories